# sum values of an array when keys are not values of another array

Tags: php

i have 2 arrays:

```
$a=Array 
( 
[25] => 21.00 
[33] => 63.00
[12] => 45.00
[14] => 12.00
[17] => 22.00
)
$b=Array
(
[0] => 24 
[1] => 25 
[3] => 14
)
```

I want to sum only the values of array $a that their keys do not much the values of array $b.
For instance in this example the output would be 130.
Any idea would be appreciated.Thanks in advance!

Comment: My array_diff/array_flip method was incorrect, therefor removed. Too many unpredictable outcomes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$a = array( 
    25 => 21.00,
    33 => 63.00,
    12 => 45.00,
    14 => 12.00,
    17 => 22.00,
);
$b = array(24, 25, 14);

$result = array_sum(
    array_diff_key(
        $a,
        array_flip($b)
    )
);
var_dump($result);
```

Comment: Array_diff_key, exactly what mine was missing, nice.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$sum = 0;
foreach($a as $arr => $value_a){
   $find = 0;
   foreach($b as $arr_b => $value_b){
       if($arr == $value_b)
           $find = 1;
   }
   if($find == 0)
      $sum += $value_a
}

echo'sum: '.$sum;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably one of the most readable ways. What's the purpose of this because there are more efficient ways for sure that only require one loop.

```
$total = 0;
foreach($a as $k => $v){
    $sum = true;
    foreach($b as $kk => $vv){
        if($vv == $k){
            $sum = false;
        }
    }       
    if($sum){
        $total += $v;
    }
}
```